# Running Karma tests with google maps module dependency

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, testing, karma-runner

So i included this module into my Angular app https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps

Now the question is: How to I run Karma tests that integrate it?

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.6 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/Work/status/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.8.4)]: Connected on socket iLYLgPcHaw8HVJjNNafq
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.8.4) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at /Users/Work/status/app/scripts/angular-google-maps.min.js:6
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.8.4): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.509 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

So it is the global google object that is missing

I see a couple of solutions but do not know how to implement them:

-Inject the google script everytime we run tests (although inefficient). Question is, how and where do I inject it?

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

-i read a suggestion somewhere that we could mock the google API

Comment: I suspect mocking is the way to go. Can you post a short test that is failing?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I have 1 extremely basic test setup. But it does not even get to run because of this Uncaught ReferenceError with the google object. Hence the 0 of 0 ERROR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked a few times already in the issues list on the project. Here is one of the q/a.
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/270

Comment: the link is broken @nick

Comment: I re-enabled issues on the repo. Be nice if  someone would like to enlighten me on how I can lock issue creation on a github repo but allow existing issues to be seen.

Comment: Looks like this would work, https://blog.github.com/2017-11-08-archiving-repositories/ .

Comment: Repo has been archived and all issues still exist.